# JSON dumps indent tab

Tags: json, python-2.7

I use Python 2.7 and I want to change the indention of JSON.dumps() to TABS instead of SPACES. When you do indent=8, it will insert 8 spaces, but I want to insert 2 tabs. I have read that this is possible in Python 3.3 by doing indent="\t\t" but we use Python 2.7.

Comment: Why not just do a regex replace after your dump?

Answer (score 6):

Well with `re.sub()` you could do the following

```
dump = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
tabs = re.sub('\n +', lambda match: '\n' + '\t' * (len(match.group().strip('\n')) / 2), dump)
```

Comment: The / 2 doesn't match the number of indented spaces, it should be 4. And use // instead of /. But this division is not necessary when json.dumps uses indent=1.
Also the search for \n can be avoided using ^ at the beginning of pattern and flags=re.MULTILINE

Answer (score 1):

The parameter indent can be a string. So this would work.

```
dump = json.dumps(data, indent="\t")
```